Venues for the dissemination of research proposals
A bit of background: I studied mathematics at a Dutch university, and graduated some years ago. Although I didn't pursue a PhD degree in this direction, I have always maintained a deep interest in the subject. Recently, I decided to summarize my ideas for research in a particular subfield - analytic number theory - in a research proposal.
This research proposal contains 15 research questions, which are accompanied by partial results and texts that motivate the questions. Although the questions sometimes relate to one another, the research proposal doesn't form a tightly integrated whole. It is more like a collection of loosely related, short mathematical essays - each of which ends with one or more questions. The proposal ends with a list of references. In total, the proposal comprises about 20 pages.
I would like to collaborate with professional mathematicians on one or more of these ideas in my spare time. However, the ones I've corresponded with so far are usually quite busy with their own work, or they are not interested. I am currently looking for ways to reach a broader audience with this research proposal, so as to find people who'd like to collaborate, or to inspire them to work on the questions themselves.
Therefore, I would like to publish the research proposal somewhere, so it can be viewed by the public. I've considered putting it on the ArXiv. At the same time, I was wondering whether there are other venues that were specifically created for the purpose of dissemminating documents that contain research proposals with research-level questions in mathematics. Do such venues exist? If so, could you give me some advice on where and how to make this proposal publicly available?

You seem to have made this a "shopping question". See the help center: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

@Buffy I'm not sure what you mean by that

Note that if you publish this, then there is no guarantee that someone reading it won't take up the question(s) independently from you. It might not result in collaboration. Ideas for research are free. You might get an acknowledgement, and maybe not even that if they avoid plagiarism.

@Buffy I do realize that. It's a risk I might take. I do think people ought to cite the proposal if they employ one of the methods or results I describe within it

I wrote a paper a bit like that once. It was a summary of a subfield, with a bunch of open problems at the end: An overview of schema theory
I put in on arXiv, where it sat for many years, periodically being cited. That led me to want to get the paper peer reviewed and published so people would feel more confident relying on it. And so I published in the Graduate Journal of Mathematics, where I subsequently became an editor.
I think it's a great service to the community to share open problems that young people might like to work on. I wrote something before on Mathoverflow to that effect: Math papers where the only issue is that someone else could've done it but didn't
My advice to you, if you are willing to let others work on the problems, is to put it on arXiv and then consider submitting it to a journal like the graduate journal of math, or one of the journals listed here: Publishing conjectures

Thank you for your answer. Could I send the proposal to you? Then you could see which parts - if any - would be appropriate for publication in the Graduate Journal of Mathematics

@MaxMuller Sure, go ahead. My email address is easy to find. Looking forward to reading your paper.
